# Digraph with no even cycle

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Let D be a digraph with no even directed cycle. Prove that D has at most one
kernel.

Could someone please help with a proof?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two different kernels $A$ and $B$. Here are a couple of hints:

1. $A \setminus B$ and $B \setminus A$ must be non empty.
2. The induced graph on $(A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$ is bipartite, and all its vertices have indegree at least 1.

This is enough to conclude that there is an even directed cycle, i.e. a contradiction.

Comment: But how did you conclude that $(A\B) \cup (B\A)$ is bipartite and have indegree at least 1??

Comment: 1. The definition of a kernel says that none of the vertices in a kernel are adjacent (so no pair of vertices in $A$ can be adjacent, and similarly for $B$, and hence no pair of vertices in $(A\setminus B)$ can be adjacent.and similarly for $(B\setminus A)$). Hence, $(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$ is bipartite.

2. Also by the def. of a kernel, every vertex in $V\setminus A$ must be adjacent to at least one vertex in $A$. In particular, these edges go from $A$ to $V\setminus A$. So every vertex in $(B\setminus A)$ "receives" an edge from $A$). Similarly for $B$ and $(A\setminus B)$.